# C# Winui3 titleBar problem, make it movable

Tags: c#, winui-3

Recently, I started developing an application with Winui3 c#. However, once I attempted to fully customize the application's title bar, the ability to move the window was lost. I need someone to help me implement a function to enable window movement

Comment: You can find info about title bar customization [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk). At the moment, there's the **WinAppSDK** way, and the **WinUI 3** way. I know that this shouldn't be this complicated but it seems that this will become easier in the near future. You need to be more specific about how you need to customize your title bar and where do you need help. Code around your current title bar customization also helps help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that I haven't explained myself very well. I'm using WinUI EX to customize the title bar, and I'm trying to achieve a look similar to the title bar of Microsoft's PC Booster program. However, when I use ExtendendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;, I'm unable to hide the Maximize/minimize buttons.

Comment: But it's not just that issue. When I hide the complete title bar with IsTitleBarVisible = false;, the same thing happens as with WinForms when there's no title bar - the functionality of moving the window is lost

Comment: About that last comment... how do you expect to move the window without a title bar? You need to manually add the behavior if you want any part of the window to be draggable.

Comment: The 3rd extension WinUIEx uses [OverlappedPresenter](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx/blob/5e179c280788be8f32fa3c95401d741ebcd3c822/src/WinUIEx/WindowManager.cs#L510) to [Set the title bar invisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.overlappedpresenter.setborderandtitlebar?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2). Try [`AppWindow.TitleBar.SetDragRectangles(dragRects);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk#interactive-content)